# The left and right expressions type must be of the same type - JPQL

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I'm using JPA with EclipseLink and I'm getting this warning:

> The left and right expressions type must be of the same type.

on this line:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM AuthToken auth, User u WHERE
     u.id = auth.user AND auth.token = :mytoken", User.class);
```

`em` is my `EntityManager`

Can someone explain me why is this warning showing up and how to fix it?

I'm not very familiar with `JPQL` and `JOINs` so please bear with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove condition `u.id = auth.user` and check whether you still get the error. Shouldn't it be:

```
u.id = auth.user.id
```

Comment: I removed and I don't get the warning anymore. Nevertheless I still need that comparison to make sure I get one `user` and the `user` I need

Comment: You got it mate, thanks! Normal SQL was messing with my lacking skills in JPQL. I see I've to go the "object" oriented way,  navigating thru the columns.